# JavaScript + DOM code within Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby, dom

How can I execute javascript + DOM code within ruby? I want a gem like harmony but not so buggy (harmony uses johnson, which has a compilation problems with ruby >= 1.9.1).

Comment: Not sure if it will offer DOM manipulation, but perhaps [ExecJS](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs) can help.

Comment: Yes, I already saw this gem, but I dont know how to manipulate with DOM objects using ExecJS :(